# Special file in linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-permissions

As a beginner am asking how to know if file is special in linux? Is there any command show this data?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the `file` command:

```
cd /dev
file tty
```

This will output something like this:`tty: character special`

Telling you that the file "tty" is a special file of the character type. There are also block specials as well.

See: `man file` or https://linux.die.net/man/1/file for more on the `file` command.

Answer (score -1):

Without defining what a special file is, I assume that a "file" that is not a file is a special file.

A directory is a special file, as a pipe or a symlink, etc. If so :

`ls -l | grep ^-` will only give you the "normal" file.

To find only the "special" files `ls -l | grep -v ^-`

By the way, *everything is a file* in linux.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean [`device files`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) you can use `file` utility to check, for example:

```
$ file /dev/sda
/dev/sda: block special (8/0)
$ file /dev/null
/dev/null: character special (1/3)
```

You can also use `GNU ls` with `-l`:

```
$ ls -l /dev/null
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Jan 20 20:54 /dev/null
$ ls -l /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Jan 20 20:54 /dev/sda
```

As described in the documentation:

```
 The file type is one of the following characters:
 (...)
  ‘b’
      block special file
  ‘c’
      character special file
```

Or `stat`:

```
$ stat /dev/sda
  File: '/dev/sda'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   block special file
Device: 6h/6d   Inode: 10245       Links: 1     Device type: 8,0
Access: (0660/brw-rw----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    6/    disk)
Access: 2018-01-20 20:54:41.153354807 +0100
Modify: 2018-01-20 20:54:41.153354807 +0100
Change: 2018-01-20 20:54:41.153354807 +0100
 Birth: -

$ stat /dev/null
  File: '/dev/null'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   character special file
Device: 6h/6d   Inode: 1029        Links: 1     Device type: 1,3
Access: (0666/crw-rw-rw-)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2018-01-20 20:54:41.124354808 +0100
Modify: 2018-01-20 20:54:41.124354808 +0100
Change: 2018-01-20 20:54:41.124354808 +0100
 Birth: -
```